# is there a way where I can empty the array using shift function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here I am trying to empty an array using recursion by calling shift function, but anyhow I am getting an error please help.

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4];
function del(arr){
    if(arr.length === 0){
        return []
    }else {
        let result = arr.shift();
        return del(result)
    }
}
console.log(del(arr))
```

> ```
>    TypeError: arr.shift is not a function
> ```

Comment: what sense does it make to empty an array and return finally a new array?

Comment: I don't friend help would be great.

Comment: `let result = arr.shift();` Reading [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)  *"The shift() method removes the first element from an array and **returns that removed element**."*

Comment: Simple console.log() line would have made this so clear.  `let result = arr.shift(); console.log(result);  return del(result);`

Comment: You're problem can be solved by removing excess code. (I mean, why not reduce `del` to just `arr.length = 0`?)

Answer (score 2):

You need to handover the array after shifting an item.

[`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) returns/removes the item at index zero or `undefined` if the array is empty.

```js
function del(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) return arr;
    arr.shift();
    return del(arr);
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];      // keep the variable/omit reassignment
                               // just to give proof

console.log(del(arr) === arr); // same object reference
console.log(arr);              // empty array
```

Comment: Ok is it possible that I put the arr.shift inside the del(arr.shift()) will that work?

Comment: @AliayubAli `arr.shift()` returns the shifted element, NOT the array.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is empty the array, you can do:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.splice(0, arr.length);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: That's not the OP's question, or why not `arr.length = 0` or `arr = []` (if the array is mutable)??

Comment: @code There are circumstances where you cannot reassign the reference to a blank array, because something else is referencing the original array and you want the array to look empty for that reference too. I was guessing that was the reason for the OP to use shift().

Comment: You _can_ set the length to 0. (The second one preceded "if the array is mutable").

Comment: @code great point, yes, I like your approach better.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say:

> The shift() method removes the first element from an array and returns that removed element. This method changes the length of the array.

Instead of returning `del(result)`, which will call `del` with the shifted element as argument, you should call `del(arr)`.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4];
function del(arr){
    if(arr.length === 0){
        return []
    }else {
        let result = arr.shift(); //not using result, so no need to declare that variable
        return del(arr)
    }
}
console.log(del(arr))
```